# (answered) php or js: Is there a way to echo something at the area you are typing?

Tags: javascript, php

The answer is using a html[pre] tag to insert the text into the database.

So I have a `<textarea id="something" name ="name"></textarea>` 
 where you can write something for the contents of the post. Problem is, you need to type br instead of enter because of my shitty way of programming a database.

So I made a little javascript program that detects the keypress of enter and echos it (this is litterally the first thing I ever did with javascript) and it works somehow [code](http://prntscr.com/s28v0e) or:

```
var input = document.getElementById("id"); // put the id of where you want to put this
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) { //looks if key is pressed <br>
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {  //13 is the enter key <br>
   document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = 'text'; //echos it?
  }
});
```

But I don't know how I can paste the br in the correct spot (inside the textarea), is there any way to do it? If there is a php solution I would much rather use that, because I actually know how it works.

Comment: Would [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) help in any way?

Comment: This all sounds so wrong and convulted.... Can you tell us a bit more about what you are doing here and why?

Comment: @kerbholz - probably, but then it sounds like there is a major HTML injection vulnerability here...

Comment: Please include the code in your question instead of using an image. That way we can use your code to test it out.

Comment: Why would you need to convert newlines to <br> on input? Doesn't it make more sense to do it on output?

Comment: @ZeusBeer This still sounds sooo wrong! Tell me, if I enter `This is <b>bold</b> text` in your textarea, does it show up bold? And what if I enter `<script>alert('yo!');</script>`? If both of these actually work, then you have a MAJOR security issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is to show the text entered in the textarea field as the same format. Then you can use an alternative way to achieve your goal.

use *pre* tag to show your text

Example:

```
<pre> "your text" </pre>
```

The *pre* tag displays the text without formatting by browser again. But it retains the format at the time of insertion into the textarea field

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it should be the other way around—textareas are preformatted, they don't require `<br>` tags in them. As some of the commenters noted, it would be helpful to understand what you are trying to do to suggest a simpler way of doing it.

However, to directly answer your question, you can detect current cursor position in a textarea with jQuery:

```
$('#something').prop('selectionStart');
```

That way you can insert any string in that position, for example (not really good code, just an example):

```
$('#something').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        let pos = $(this).prop('selectionStart');
        let text = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(text.slice(0, pos) + '<br>' + text.slice(pos));
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w7349rqj/